# Failed to create log file on application directory?

Tags: coldfusion

I want to write a log file for my application. The path where I want to store the file is:

```
destination::"C:\ColdFusion8\wwwroot\autosyn\logs"
```

I have used the sample below to generate the log file:

```
<cfset destination = expandPath('logs')>
<cfoutput>destination::"#destination#"</cfoutput><br/>
<cflog file='#destination#/test' application="yes" text="Running test log.">
```

When I supply the full path, it didn't create a log file. When I remove my destination, and only provide a file name, the log is generated in the ColdFusion server path C:\ColdFusion8\logs.

How can I generate a log file in my application directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the description of attribute *file* according to [cflog](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_j-l_06.html) tag specs:

> Message file. Specify only the main part of the filename. For example,
>   to log to the Testing.log file, specify "Testing".
>   The file **must be located in the default log directory**. **You cannot
>   specify a directory path**. If the file does not exist, it is created
>   automatically, with the extension .log.

You can use [cffile](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_f_11.html) tag to write information into the custom folder.

Answer (score 3):

From the docs for [`<cflog>`](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/Tags_j-l_06.html):

> file
>
> Optional
>
> Message file. Specify only the main part of the filename. For example, to log to the Testing.log file, specify "Testing".
>   The file must be located in the default log directory. **You cannot specify a directory path**. If the file does not exist, it is created automatically, with the extension .log.

(My **emphasis**).

Reading the docs is always a good place to start when wondering how things might work.

So `<cflog>` will only log to the ColdFusion logs directory, and that is by design.

I don't have CF8 handy, but you would be able to set the logging directory to be a different one via either the CFAdmin UI (CF9 has this, I just confirmed), or `neo-logging.xml` in `WEB-INF/cfusion/lib`.

Or you could use a different logging mechanism. I doubt it will work on a rusty of CF8 install, but perhaps [LogBox](http://logbox.riaforge.org/)?